# How to test stores/actions?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, reactjs-flux, jestjs

I need to test the alt store; for which I have raised an action using alt dispatcher and trying to listen it at the action listener. But I got my alt object as undefined.

Action Class:

```
var alt = require('../alt');
var LocationSource = require('../sources/LocationSource');

class LocationActions {
    updateLocations(locations) {
        this.dispatch(locations);
    }

    fetchLocations() {
        this.dispatch();
        var actionDispatcher = this;

        LocationSource.fetchLocations().then(function(items) {

            actionDispatcher.actions.updateLocations(items);

        });
    }

    locationsFailed(errorMessage) {
        this.dispatch(errorMessage);
    }

    favoriteLocation(location) {
        this.dispatch(location);
    }

    fetchedLocation(location) {
        this.dispatch(location);
    }

    fetchLocation(locationId) {

        var actionDispatcher = this;

        actionDispatcher.dispatch();

        LocationSource.fetchLocation(locationId).then(function(item) {

            actionDispatcher.actions.fetchedLocation(item);

        });
    }
}

module.exports = alt.createActions(LocationActions);
```

My Store:

```
var alt = require('../alt');
var LocationActions = require('../actions/LocationActions');

class FavoritesStore {
    constructor() {
        this.locations = [];

        this.bindListeners({
            addFavoriteLocation: LocationActions.FAVORITE_LOCATION
        });
    }

    addFavoriteLocation(location) {
        this.locations.push(location); 
    }

    onRemoveFavoriteLocation(){

    }

}

module.exports = alt.createStore(FavoritesStore, 'FavoritesStore');
```

MY Alt js:

```
var Alt = require('alt');
var alt = new Alt();
var chromeDebug = require('alt/utils/chromeDebug')

chromeDebug(alt);

module.exports = alt;
```

Heres the test file:

```
"use strict";
jest.dontMock('../src/js/stores/FavoritesStore');
jest.dontMock('../src/js/actions/LocationActions');
jest.dontMock('../src/js/alt');
import alt from '../src/js/alt';
var fav =require('../src/js/stores/FavoritesStore');

import LocationActions from '../src/js/actions/LocationActions';

describe('fav', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        sinon.spy(alt.dispatcher, 'dispatch');

        alt.dispatch(LocationActions.FAVORITE_LOCATION, {id:15, name:'khi'});
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        // clean up our sinon spy so we do not affect other tests
        alt.dispatch.restore();

    });
    it('add a location to favorites list ', function() {

        var id: 15, name: 'San Francisco' ,
        action = LocationActions.FAVORITE_LOCATION;
        console.log({id:15, name:'khi'});
        // fire the action
        LocationActions.favoriteLocation({id:15, name:'khi'});

    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this already resolved but there is(was) an issue with ES6 `import`s and jest mocking instructions. Babel/babel-jest (the tool I guess you are using) will hoist (pull to the very top) and `import`-statements during compilation. This means the `import alt from '../src/js/alt';` is run before your call to `jest.dontMock('../src/js/alt');`. This could results in `alt` being mocked.